# Making a half circle hero image with css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a half circle on the screen over which I can put buttons and other things just like [AdminBro](https://adminbro.com/) top blue color circle but a little bit smaller. I did it like this:

```css
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.eclipse {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200vw;
    height: 200vw;
    left: -50vw;
    top: -180vw;
    background-color: #41B3A3;
    border-radius: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="eclipse"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see this is a react application. The thing is I am not getting the desired result please tell me why?

Comment: Inspect element: `body.landing .main-hero { background: #4268F6;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 300px 40% 160px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
    margin: -250px -30% 0;
    text-align: center; }`

Comment: Yes sir this seems familiar with the inspect element of admin bro, the thing is, can you explain it a bit as how and why this works and mine doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

There's an easier way to this. You can simply use [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) property of CSS.

Create a `div` element with a background color below body tag and give it an absolute position and full width and height. Then use `clip-path` to create a create clipping path.

HTML

```
<div class="ellipse"></div>
```

CSS

```
.div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: cyan;
    clip-path: ellipse(80% 50% at 50% 5%);
}
```

You can play around with the values. Also this [clip-path generator](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) is a useful tool.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if I understand your question, but if you just want to make a half circle, try this:

```
.half-circle {
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px; /* needs to be half of the width */
   border: 10px solid black;
   border-bottom: none;
   background: green;
   border-radius: 110px 110px 0 0;
}
```

Note, how the border-radius is 100px (height) + border-width (10px). If you don't need a border the border-radius of the top two corners is just equal to your height.